# Run unit test code from zip file

Tags: python-2.7, package, python-unittest

I followed this tutorial to create a self contained python application.
http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/10/bundling-python-files-into-stand-alone.html

What I would like to do is create a unit test application within a similar self contained application and, in addition, have several fiels within the unit test application itself.

I have a directory structure as follows:
src/
    src1.py
    src2.py
    **main**.py
test/
    **main**.py
    **init**.py

My unittest application packages up the src and test files to create a self-contained unit test application. I currently have all my test code in test/**main**.py and would like to separate the test code into different files (i.e. test1.py, test2.py, etc). However, when I try to do so, it either can't import them or I get import errors.

What is the correct way to implement this scheme? I am using the unittest module in Python 2.7 and would like to continue using these.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got this working by following this:
http://blakesmith.me/2009/09/14/getting-started-with-python-unit-testing.html
Instead of calling it suite.py, I called it **main**.py and it worked within a zip file.